# Should we and how to name react-navigation screen prop types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

According to the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-screens) about type checking, we have to name our navigation prop type like this:

```js
type HomeScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<StackParamList, 'Home'>;
type HomeScreenRouteProp = RouteProp<StackParamList, 'Home'>;

interface Props {
  navigation: HomeScreenNavigationProp,
  route: HomeScreenRouteProp,
}
```

And change `Home` by the each screen name.

But this can be easily simplified to this:

```js
type Navigation = StackNavigationProp<StackParamList, 'Home'>;
type Route = RouteProp<StackParamList, 'Home'>;

interface Props {
  navigation: Navigation,
  route: Route,
}
```

Or even simpler, declaring type directly on the Props interface like this:

```js
interface Props {
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<StackParamList, 'Home'>,
  route: RouteProp<StackParamList, 'Home'>,
}
```

With the same result.

Is there any technical reason to avoid what I am doing and name the prop types like described on the documentation?

If not, is there any convention about type naming with react-navigation and/or react-native?

Comment: It doesn't say you have to name it any particular way. Just do what is readable

Comment: Thanks, but in many languages and frameworks, there are official recommendation to follow. This is why I post this question. :-)